# How can I make an my HTML columns adjustable width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I have a HTML application that works with three columns, each of which is a div in a container object.

---

```
     |        |    
 A   |   B    | C
     |        |
```

---

I'd like to make it such that the three columns would each be adjustable, and the text would reflow and adjust inside of them.

This works trivially with Frames (See: http://www.tizag.com/pics/htmlT/frameindex.html ), but I'd like to replicate this behavior with my Divs.

Is there a jQuery plugin to do this? The best way I can think of is to create a slider div between the contents, similar to the implementation at http://www.catchmyfame.com/2010/08/12/adjustable-columns-with-jquery/

Is there any easier/cleaner/prettier way? This seems like it has to be a pretty standard request...

Answer (score 1):

A rudimentary way to set them up all the same width:

```
div {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    }
```

If you want to allow the user to resize the columns with a drag-n-drop method then you'll want to look into a JS framework. Here's a jQuery example:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Resizable

Comment: I'm entirely open to using a jQuery solution, but I don't see any way in that example to lock multiple divs, so that if I drag A to the left, B comes with it?

Comment: What if you had a div within a div with the `grouped` columns that look like they are columns?